# Facebook Login Error when it's not the first time I login to this application

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-login

I have a cordova application (6.3.1) and I use this plugin to implement a facebook connection : https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

But I have a problem on Android and I can't understand where it comes from.

I installed and setup my facebook connect with an FB app. Everything works well when it's the first time I give the authorization to this app. If I try to reconnect again (even on a fresh app installation) I got the following message : "Facebook error: Login Error: There is an error in …ou into this application. Please try again later"
But if I unlink the application from my FB account manually, it works ! It's really weird cuz I got this problem on my live FB app only, and not on the development FB apps.

On iOS it works perfectly !

What could be the reason ? Is there a specific configuration that I need to add ?

Thanks !